# При изменении значения одной переменной меняется значение другой, причём ID у них разные

Tags: python

Делал я одну программку и столкнулся с одним неприятным багом. Проблема  возникает в Python *v3.9.0*.

Есть у меня переменная ***i***, которая принимает с каждой итерацией ***for*** значения элементов ***list1***. Также есть переменная ***foo***, которая хранит в себе копию ***i***. Так вот, если изменить переменную ***foo***, то ***i*** меняется вместе с ней, как будто имя ***foo*** и имя ***i*** ссылаются на одно и то же значение.

Мне нужно, чтобы ***foo*** не влияла на ***i***, но при этом принимала её значение вначале цикла.

Вот код:

```
list1 = [                       #проблема возникает вроде только со списками такого типа - [ [[a1, …],[a2, …]], [[b1, …],[b2, …]], …]
    [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
]
for i in list1:
    foo = i[:]                  # имя foo ссылается на копию i
    # print(id(i1), id(foo))
    foo[1].append(9)            # после foo обязательно должен стоять [индекс какого-либо элемента foo], иначе баг не появится
    print(i)
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
>>> [[1, 2], [3, 4]
```

Фактический результат:

```
>>> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 9]]
```

Comment: много скобок у list1, у меня только одна 9 добавляется.

Comment: `foo = i[:]`  это _shallow copy_, т.е. копируются только элементы списка, без субэлементов, на которые эти элементы ссылаются. Поэтому, например, `foo[1]` продолжает указывать на тот же список что и `i[1]`, соответственно 
 `foo[1].append(9)` сделает тоже что и `i[1].append(9)`.

Comment: _Vladimir Gamalyan_ Впредь буду знать о такой штуке как глубина копирования, спасибо вам :)

Comment: _TigerTV.ru_ Да там добавляется одна 9, исправил.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно, у `foo` и `i` айдишники будут разные. Зато если посмотрите `id(foo[1])` и `id(i[1])` - то эти айдишники будут одинаковыми.

При копировании создаётся новый список, а потом в него вставляются ссылки на элементы оригинала. Если хотите, чтобы и внутренние списки копировались по значению, то нужно использовать `deepcopy`

```
from copy import deepcopy

foo = deepcopy(i)  # вместо foo = i[:]
```